# How to mock a C++ enum for the Qt Quick Designer?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have a C++ enum defined like this:

```
namespace SectionIdNamespace
{
    Q_NAMESPACE
    enum SectionId {
        SomeValue
    };
    Q_ENUM_NS(SectionId)
};
```

I register that enum as follows:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject(
    SectionIdNamespace::staticMetaObject,
    "SectionIdImportName",
    1, 0,
    "SectionId",
    "Error: only enums"
);
```

And use it in QML:

```
import SectionIdImportName 1.0
....
SectionId.SomeValue
```

When opening that QML file in the Qt Quick Designer (the "Design" tab in the Qt Creator), it refuses to load the file and says `QML module not found (SectionIdImportName)`, since the Designer does not run any C++ code.

How can I make the Designer work with that QML file that uses a C++ enum?

I am aware of `QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH` and [QML enumeration attributes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#enumeration-attributes). I tried to "mock" the C++ enum by such an QML enum just for the Designer, however, those enum's values are used like this `QMLType.EnumType.EnumValue`, while the C++ enum values must be adressed just with `EnumType.EnumValue`. It seems like the code can be compatible to either a C++ enum or a QML enum, but not both at the same time.

I'm using Qt 5.11, upgrading to 5.12 soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working both on runtime and designer with the enum encapsulated in a class:

```
class SectionIdWrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    enum class SectionIdEnum {
        SomeValue
    };
    Q_ENUM(SectionIdEnum);
};
```

And register like:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<SectionIdWrapper>("your.namespace", 1, 0, "SectionId", "Error: only enum");
```

And usage in Qml like expected:

```
import your.namespace 1.0

Item {
    property int test: SectionId.SomeValue
}
```

Note that the name of the enum is not used.

You can add more enums in that same class, but then the names might collide (either domain-wise or text-wise)

Comment: As far as I can see, that is similar to what I have already. I can access the C++ enum from QML just like you do. But for me, the designer fails at the import statement. In your case, how does the designer know that your.namespace exists? It never runs the C++ code with the call to qmlRegisterUncreatableType.

Comment: I had troubles with `QT_ENUM_NS` and this worked for me, so that's why I answered. As for the designer, I sometimes see it failing to grab new qmlRegister calls, but after building they work (if correct). I think Qt Creator has some internal parser that looks through all the project files finding the qmlRegister calls, or maybe the MOC makes a cache.

Comment: Indeed, It's a bug in the qt creator: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20569. `qmlRegisterUncreatableType` works, `qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject` does not. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!